I want to UV unwrap by referring only to the edge length
First of all, I want you to look at the image

I want to extrude the edges using geometry nodes
When I do that, I want to create UVs that are squashed like the bottom left of the image, but is there a way to do that?
Also, I want to be able to maintain the UV Map when I apply the modifier
I've tried making my own, but the UV Map disappears when I apply it
Can someone please tell me?

I guess the best solution would be doing it directly in the shader, without UV:
If you take only one coordinate among X, Y, Z, you end up with a one dimensional texture space.
In the image:

Left side: regular shading with object coordinates
Right side: one-dimensoinal shading with object coordinates


You can do it also drawing from the 'UV' in the "Texture Coordinate" node, then you can unwrap regularly as you would, and have control of which edges go where in the map. (Just remember that UV has only X and Y coordinates)
